# Create a new category with data for store_id 0

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I'm trying to create new categories. My code, which is called in the admin panel, looks this way:

```
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\CategoryInterface $parentCategory */
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\CategoryInterfaceFactory $this->categoryFactory */
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface $this->categoryRepository */
$data = [
    'parent_id' => $parentCategory->getEntityId(),
    'name' => ucwords(strtolower($name)),
    'is_active' => 1,
    'is_anchor' => 0,
    'include_in_menu' => 1,
    'url_key' => strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $name)),
    'display_mode' => 'PAGE',
    'page_layout' => '1column'
];
$category = $this->categoryFactory->create();
$category->setData($data)
    ->setAttributeSetId($category->getDefaultAttributeSetId());
$this->categoryRepository->save($category);
```

Although categories created this way do get created, all the data is being added for store_id 1 instead of 0. Because of this, my categories lack name (among other stuff) when seen on the category listing in the admin panel.

What I tried:

- Setting the `store_id` on a category before saving it (it was just a blind guess, not a result of any research), like this: `$category->setStoreId(0)->setData($data)`
- Emulating area code in a similar way it's done in sample data modules, this way:

  ```
  /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\State $this->appState */
  $this->appState->emulateAreaCode(
          'setup',
          [$this, 'getCategory'],
          ['name' => $name, 'parentCategory' => $parentCategory]
      );
  ```

  where `getCategory` is a method wrapping up the code pasted at the beginning of the post.

None of those methods succeeded, though. What do I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured that out already. The following code needs to be placed before the code that creates a category:

```
$this->storeManager->setCurrentStore('admin');
```

In case someone else has the same problem and doesn't know this, the storeManager property needs to be included in the construct, like everything else, this way:

```
public function __construct(
    // all the other stuff you need here
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
) {
    // all the other stuff you need here
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
}
```